# Quicksort not sorting one element in the list of strings

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
int Partition(vector<string>& userIDs, int i, int k) {
    int pivot = (i + (k - i) / 2);
    string temp;
    
    while(i<k) {
        cout << "pivot:" << pivot << endl;
        while (userIDs.at(i).compare(userIDs.at(pivot))<0) {
            cout << "1. i:"<<i<<" UserIDs.at(i):" << userIDs.at(i) << " UserID.at(pivot): " << userIDs.at(pivot) << endl;
            i += 1;
        }
        while (userIDs.at(pivot).compare(userIDs.at(k))<0) {
            cout << "2. k:" << k << " UserIDs.at(k):" << userIDs.at(k) << " UserID.at(pivot): " << userIDs.at(pivot) << endl;
            k -= 1;
        }

        if(i<k){
            cout << "3. i:" << i << " k:"<<k<<" UserIDs.at(i):" << userIDs.at(i) << " UserID.at(k) : " << userIDs.at(k) << endl;
            temp = userIDs.at(i);
            userIDs.at(i) = userIDs.at(k);
            userIDs.at(k) = temp;
            i++;
            k--;
        }
        cout << "4. i:" << i << " k:" << k << endl;
    }
    cout << " 5. k:" << k << endl;
    return k;
}

void Quicksort(vector<string>& userIDs, int i, int k) {
    cout << "Quicksort i:" << i << " k:" << k << endl;
    if (i >= k) {
        return;
    }
    int lowEndIndex = Partition(userIDs, i, k);
    cout << "Quicksort lowEndIndex:" << lowEndIndex << endl;
    Quicksort(userIDs, i, lowEndIndex);
    Quicksort(userIDs, lowEndIndex+1, k);
}
```

When I input this list:

```
BigBen
GardenHeart
GreyMare
TeenPunch
WhiteSand
LifeRacer
Doom
AlienBrain
```

I get:

```
AlienBrain
BigBen
GreyMare
GardenHeart
Doom
LifeRacer
TeenPunch
WhiteSand
```

Why is `Doom` not in the correct place?

Comment: Seems like `GardenHeart` is also in the wrong place. `GardenHeart` is second in the original list, `Doom` is second to last, and they both end up in the middle. That may be a clue. I'd print the whole array after the first partition is completed, just to see if the partition worked correctly.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/hK4PbnzEP confirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int Partition(vector<string>& userIDs, int i, int k) {
    int pivot = i;
    string pivotValue = userIDs[pivot];
    string temp;

    int leftIndex = i;
    int rightIndex = k;
    

    while(i<k) {
        while (userIDs[i].compare(pivotValue)<=0) {
            i++;
            if(i >= rightIndex) break;
        }
        while (pivotValue.compare(userIDs[k])<=0) {;
            k--;
            if(k <= leftIndex) break;
        }

        if(i<k){
            temp = userIDs[i];
            userIDs[i] = userIDs[k];
            userIDs[k] = temp;
        }

        
    }
            // swap
    userIDs[pivot] = userIDs[k];
    userIDs[k] = pivotValue;
    
    return k;
}

void Quicksort(vector<string>& userIDs, int i, int k) {
    if (i >= k) {
        return;
    }

    int lowEndIndex = Partition(userIDs, i, k);
    Quicksort(userIDs, i, lowEndIndex - 1);
    Quicksort(userIDs, lowEndIndex + 1, k);
}

int main() {
    
    vector<string> userIDs = {"BigBen", "GardenHeart", "GreyMare", "TeenPunch",
    "WhiteSand", "LifeRacer", "Doom", "AlienBrain" };

    Quicksort(userIDs, 0, userIDs.size() - 1);
    

    for(auto& c: userIDs) cout << c << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Fixed the code and tested. Now it works. What were the problems? 
As far as I noticed, firstly you didn't put `break()` statements within the while loops in case `i` or `k` exceeds the boundaries of the vector. I've changed the pivot from middle element to first element, but it's just my preference, you can implement the quicksort algorithm with your pivot in the middle, not a big deal. I've called first `Quicksort()` with `lowEndIndex - 1` rather than `lowEndIndex`. I've used `[]` operator rather than `at()`, but again it's my preference. I guess the main problems were that `break` stuff and calling the quicksort method with `lowEndIndex` rather than `lowEndIndex - 1`.

Output:

```cpp
AlienBrain BigBen Doom GardenHeart GreyMare LifeRacer TeenPunch WhiteSand
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sesM9Mda6